# OCMock giving error with Key Value Observing

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, ocmock

```
-(void)testPause_trial
{
    MyMediaPlayer *player = [[MyMediaPlayer alloc]init];

    id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:player];

    AVQueuePlayer* result = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init];
    result.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;

    [result addObserver:player forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

    [result addObserver:player forKeyPath:@"rate" options:0 context:nil];

    [(PTMediaPlayer*)[[mock stub] andReturn:result] createAVQueuePlayer:OCMOCK_ANY];

    //Start playing
    [player play];

    [player pause];

    [mock stopMocking];

}
```

Without this line "[(PTMediaPlayer*)[[mock stub] andReturn:result] createAVQueuePlayer:OCMOCK_ANY];", my code works fine.

But on including this line:

1. observeValueForKeyPath is not called for keypath = @"status"
2. for keypath = @"rate", I get the following error:

   observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.

   Key path: rate

   Observed object:

   Change: {
       kind = 1;
   }

   Context: 0x0"
   (
       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bcce1e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b363031 objc_exception_throw + 48
       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bd43975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
       3   Foundation                          0x000000010ace15ca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserving) observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 161
       4   Tests_new                           0x0000000125f05110 -[PTMediaPlayer observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 176
       5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51ccc __invoking_** + 140
       6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51b84 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
       7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc505f8 ***forwarding*** + 760
       8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc50278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
       9   Foundation                          0x000000010ac01820 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 349
       10  Foundation                          0x000000010ac010d7 NSKeyValueDidChange + 483
       11  Foundation                          0x000000010ace1422 NSKeyValueDidChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications + 148
       12  AVFoundation                        0x000000011b6e04f3 -[AVPlayer didChangeValueForKey:] + 47
       13  AVFoundation                        0x000000011b6e724f -[AVPlayer setRate:withVolumeRampDuration:playImmediately:rateChangeReason:] + 797
       14  AVFoundation                        0x000000011b6e730f -[AVPlayer setRate:] + 84
       15  Tests_new                           0x0000000125f3ac6a -[PTTimelineManager pause] + 250
       16  Tests_new                           0x0000000125f01706 -[PTMediaPlayer pause] + 182
       17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51ccc **invoking_** + 140
       18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51b84 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
       19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc505f8 ***forwarding*** + 760
       20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc50278 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
       21  Tests_new                           0x0000000125de49d7 -[PTMediaPlayerTests testPause_trial] + 2183
       22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51ccc **invoking_** + 140
       23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc51b84 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 308
       24  XCTest                              0x000000010b20a01a __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke.184 + 74
       25  XCTest                              0x000000010b264ae3 +[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:shouldInterruptTest:] + 36
       26  XCTest                              0x000000010b264a2e -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 54
       27  XCTest                              0x000000010b209ce3 __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke + 847
       28  XCTest                              0x000000010b269a7d -[XCUITestContext performInScope:] + 248
       29  XCTest                              0x000000010b20997f -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 175
       30  XCTest                              0x000000010b20b555 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke_2 + 42
       31  XCTest                              0x000000010b264ae3 +[XCTestCase(Failures) performFailableBlock:shouldInterruptTest:] + 36
       32  XCTest                              0x000000010b264a2e -[XCTestCase(Failures) _performTurningExceptionsIntoFailuresInterruptAfterHandling:block:] + 54
       33  XCTest                              0x000000010b20b402 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.318 + 90
       34  XCTest                              0x000000010b271061 +[XCTContext runInContextForTestCase:block:] + 225
       35  XCTest                              0x000000010b20aaff -[XCTestCase performTest:] + 673
       36  XCTest                              0x000000010b24d727 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
       37  XCTest                              0x000000010b206341 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
       38  XCTest                              0x000000010b205b1d -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 55
       39  XCTest                              0x000000010b205dde -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 296
       40  XCTest                              0x000000010b24d727 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
       41  XCTest                              0x000000010b206341 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
       42  XCTest                              0x000000010b205b1d -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 55
       43  XCTest                              0x000000010b205dde -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 296
       44  XCTest                              0x000000010b24d727 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
       45  XCTest                              0x000000010b206341 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 365
       46  XCTest                              0x000000010b205b1d -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 55
       47  XCTest                              0x000000010b205dde -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 296
       48  XCTest                              0x000000010b24d727 -[XCTest runTest] + 57
       49  XCTest                              0x000000010b27afa6 __44-[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:]_block_invoke + 40
       50  XCTest                              0x000000010b21e389 -[XCTestObservationCenter _observeTestExecutionForBlock:] + 594
       51  XCTest                              0x000000010b27adb1 -[XCTTestRunSession runTestsAndReturnError:] + 369
       52  XCTest                              0x000000010b1ecc71 -[XCTestDriver runTestsAndReturnError:] + 447
       53  XCTest                              0x000000010b26fbb1 _XCTestMain + 960
       54  xctest                              0x000000010a8a72a4 main + 571
       55  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011289b955 start + 1
   )

   Any help would be great!

Comment: did u implement the observeValueForKeyPath method ?

Comment: Yes in "MyMediaPlayer" class but it is not being called in case of keypath @"status"